# MVC4 web api model not binding when called from angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, api, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have a action method with this signature:

```
public List<Member> Get([FromUri]MemberSearchModel searchModel)
```

The model looks like this:

```
public class MemberSearchModel
    {

        public string SearchBy { get; set; }
        public string SearchValue { get; set; }
    }
```

and im calling the api like this:

```
dataFactory.getMembers = function () {
        var memberSearchModel = {
            SearchBy: 'Name',
            SearchValue: 'jaredites'
        };
        return $http.get(urlBase, memberSearchModel);
    };
```

the method is hit but the model comes through with null values

Ive tried not using [FromUri] but then the model itself is null
Ive tried [FromBody] and the model comes through as null as well.

Is there something Im missing here?

It works when I call it specifying the params in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this that :

```
dataFactory.getMembers = function () {
        var memberSearchModel = {
            SearchBy: 'Name',
            SearchValue: 'jaredites'
        };
        return $http.get(urlBase, {params: memberSearchModel});
    };
```

Comment: Oh MY GOD. No where does it say to do it that way! Thanks

Comment: The [***$http docs***](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) show the second parameter is a config object.  There's other stuff there too letting you modify the headers and response for instance.